# Javascript parsing expression with dynamically passing context variables into a parsed expression

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm trying to write a parser in javascript for an expression language that looks like this:

```
concat("hello", ${some_field})
```

These expressions get passed in as user input so there are some security risks to using it directly with javascript, like template literals, for example.

in which I would pass some context like

```js
{
    some_field: 'world'
}
```

I was thinking ideally my javascript would look like this:

```js
const parsed = Parser.parse('concat("hello", ${some_field})');
const res = parsed.execute({
    some_field: 'world'
});
```

I was looking into parsing libraries and found [peg.js](https://pegjs.org/online) but am a bit unfamiliar with how to incorporate something like this into it. Any tips on this?

Edit:

For more context, the language I'm trying to parse is from the "calculations" in the xform specification on the [odk xform docs](https://getodk.github.io/xforms-spec/#xpath-functions)

Comment: What about native JavaScript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: I updated my question @Pointy. I'm not sure template literals would work in this case since I'm taking text input from a variable and trying to parse, then execute it.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute"? Are you going to implement your own interpreter? Or do you want to evaluate the expanded code as JavaScript?

Comment: For a simple expression language that consists only of function calls, string literals, and context variables, it's probably easier to write a parser by hand instead of using a library like peg.

Comment: Its a bit more complicated than just the simple expression I gave, there's nested function calls, lots of operators. I'll update the question with a link to the language I'm trying to parse

Comment: Writing a parser for a language of even modest complexity is not a small project. Even if you use a tool like PEG, you have to understand how to express your grammar the way you want it and then feed it to the parser generator, and then augment the parser with actions that carry out your desired semantics.

Comment: yep, I understand that. Its not an easy task, I agree. I think I'm getting some progress, it looks like peg can accept "options" - which might be the route to go.

```

const result = parser.parse("boo", {
  validWords: [ "boo", "baz", "boop" ]
});
```

Comment: @twoLeftFeet In that case, you probably should rather find a library that already implements the xpath expression language. For the context variables you could either a) do simple text replacement before parsing, like C macros, b) introduce another xpath function `getContext('some_field')` instead that follows the syntax and can be evaluated by the library or c) a mix of these approaches

Comment: I'll have a look around. Thanks for the suggestions!